# 関数定義の引数リストの後ろにある -> の意味

Tags: python

def 関数名(param1, param2) -> None:

という記述を見かけたのですが、-> Noneの部分は何をやっているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「関数の返値はNone型です」、という意味です。
つまり、その関数は何も返さないということになります。

以前からその書き方で説明している文章はありましたが、Python3.5から導入された「型ヒント」でもその記法が採用されています。
http://docs.python.jp/3.5/library/typing.html