# Pythonの関数における->について

Tags: python

Pythonの関数に以下のような記述があったのですが．

```
def hoge(string) -> str:
    return string
```

このような関数における，この「->」の意味を調べたいのですが，
記号だったせいで検索できず大変困っております．
この演算子？の意味をお知りの方いらっしゃいましたらご教授いただければと思います．
どうかよろしくお願いいたします．失礼致します．

Comment: 関数の返値の型を表します。以前に似た[質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/24567/%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E5%AE%9A%E7%BE%A9%E3%81%AE%E5%BC%95%E6%95%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E5%BE%8C%E3%82%8D%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%AE%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3)があります。

Answer (score 2):

関数のアノテーションです。その例の場合、関数の戻り値が文字列型になることを表します。

http://docs.python.jp/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#function-annotations
http://docs.python.jp/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function

Comment: この質問は重複でクローズになると思いますので、[あちらの質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/24567/)に回答を付けたほうがよさそうです。あちらには既に回答が一つありますが、「アノテーション」という言葉を説明したこの回答も有意義だと思います。